# d3 - Having trouble plotting circles to represent frequency of audio clip versus time

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I'm fairly new to d3 and I'm working on a project which involves taking in an audio clip and plotting the frequency/pitch versus time in a graph. I would like to represent the data points with circles.

The x-axis would be time, and the y-axis would be pitch at a given time x. The radius of each circle would be related to the volume of the clip at a given time x.

My first question is - how do I pull this pitch data repeatedly? And how would I find the average/representative "pitch" to plot? From what I understand, the frequencyBinCount gives you a whole range of frequencies and gives you a value from 0-255 for each frequency. But I just need the "representative" frequency.

My second question is - if I want to display each dot sequentially as the clip is playing, how would I accomplish this? How do I loop through each time? Below is my code - I know there's probably glaring issues but I'm just starting out with d3. The base code was modified from [this source](https://bl.ocks.org/vaxelben/770f8c840ea034a75f777a704265f499).

Pseudocode:

1.Import audio analyser

2. Start audio
3. Loop for every second:
   -Get pitch and volume of the current audio that is playing at this moment in time (current_time).
   -Plot circle at height=pitch, x_position = current_time
4. When audio finishes, stop drawing

```html
<script>

  var audioElement = document.getElementById('audioElement');
  var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
  var audioSrc = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audioElement);
  var analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser();
  audioSrc.connect(analyser);
  audioSrc.connect(audioCtx.destination);

  var bufferSize = analyser.frequencyBinCount
  var frequencyData = new Uint8Array(bufferSize);
  analyser.getByteFrequencyData(frequencyData);

  var timeDomainData = new Uint8Array(bufferSize);
  analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(timeDomainData);

  // return average frequency
  var total = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < frequencyData.length; i++) {
    total += frequencyData[i];
  }
  var avgfreq = total / frequencyData.length;



  // return average amplitude
  var total = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < timeDomainData.length; i++) {
    total += Math.abs(timeDomainData[i] % 128);
  }
  var avgtd = total / timeDomainData.length;


  var svgHeight = window.innerHeight - 100;
  var svgWidth = window.innerWidth-10;


  // var colorScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  //   .domain([0, 150])
  //   .range(["#2c7bb6","#d7191c"]);

  
  var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('width', svgWidth)
    .attr('height', svgHeight);

  //how do I loop this while audio is playing so that it sequentially plots points?
  var circle = svg.append('circle')
    .attr('r', function() { return avgtd+2; })
    .attr('cx', function() { return svgWidth/2; })
    .attr('cy', function() { return svgHeight - avgfreq; })
    .attr('fill', function() { return 'blue'; });


</script>
```

Comment: I hear what you're trying to do.  Seems doable, and d3 is a good choice.  But what is the first question you're asking?

Comment: @Laizer Ah, yes, I forgot to add the first question back in. I've done so now! And I just now realized that using the "drawchart" function is probably a bad idea since it rewrites the previous canvas. How do I loop a "printcircle" function repeatedly...?